# Laravel 8 all routes are nginx 404 error except /

Tags: php, laravel, apache, nginx, laravel-8

I'm having trouble deploying a laravel 8 project on a product server. After installation, migration, etc, all my routes return 404 nginx error except "/". And also all styles and scripts connect to the index page only if you add in the URL /index.php

Here is my folder structure

```
htdocs
--public
    --app
    --bottstrap
    --public
    --.htaccess             
    --etc.
```

index.php is on htdocs/public/public directory, so for set all request to this folder, i'll setup my htaccess on simple way

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
```

I guess, this problem may be caused from nginx.conf  or apache.conf, but it realy hard to understand where is a trouble

my nginx.conf

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name domain.com www.domain.com;

    include letsencrypt.conf;

    location / {
        root  /srv/www/domain.com/htdocs/public;
        index index.php index.html index.htm;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;

    }

    access_log off;
    error_log /srv/www/domain.com/logs/domain.com-err;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name domain.com www.domain.com;
    #charset    utf-8;
    server_name_in_redirect off;

    if ($host ~ www.domain.com) { rewrite ^ https://example.com$request_uri? permanent; }

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.comfullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.com/privkey.pem;

    access_log off;
    #access_log /srv/www/domain.com/logs/domain.com-acc main;
    error_log /srv/www/domain.com/logs/domain.com-err;

    proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header    Host $host;

    set $proxyserver    "http://127.0.0.1:8080";
    set $imcontenttype  "text/html; charset=utf-8";
    set $docroot        "/srv/www/domain.com/htdocs/public";

    index index.php;
    root /srv/www/domain.com/htdocs/public;

    # Include parameters common to all websites
    include bx/bitrix.conf;
}
```

and here is my apache.conf

```
<VirtualHost *>
    DocumentRoot /srv/www/domain.com/htdocs/public
    ServerName domain.com
    ServerAlias www.domain.com
    ErrorLog /srv/www/domain.com/logs/domain.com-err
    # CustomLog /srv/www/domain.com/logs/domain.com-acc combined
    <IfModule mod_setenvif.c>
        SetEnvIf X-Forwarded-Proto https HTTPS=on
    </IfModule>

        <IfModule mpm_itk_module>
                AssignUserID domain.com domain.com
        </IfModule>

        <IfModule mpm_prefork_module>
                RMode config
                RUidGid domain.com domain.com
                RGroups apache
        </IfModule>

    <Location />
        php_admin_value open_basedir "none"
        php_admin_value upload_tmp_dir "/srv/www/domain.com/tmp"
        php_admin_value session.save_path "/srv/www/domain.com/tmp"
        php_admin_value upload_max_filesize "256M"
        php_admin_value post_max_size "256M"
        php_admin_value memory_limit "512M"
        php_admin_value date.timezone "UTC"
        php_admin_value max_input_vars "10000"
        php_admin_value pcre.recursion_limit "100000"
        php_admin_value realpath_cache_size "4096k"
        php_admin_value mbstring.internal_encoding "utf-8"
        php_admin_value mbstring.func_overload "0"
    php_admin_value opcache.revalidate_freq "0"
        php_admin_value opcache.max_accelerated_files "100000"
        php_admin_value opcache.memory_consumption "256"
        #php_admin_flag short_open_tag "On"
    </Location>

    <DirectoryMatch .*\.svn/.*>
         Require all denied
    </DirectoryMatch>

    <DirectoryMatch .*\.git/.*>
         Require all denied
    </DirectoryMatch>

    <DirectoryMatch .*\.hg/.*>
         Require all denied
    </DirectoryMatch>

    <Directory /srv/www/domain.com/htdocs/public>
        Options Includes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    <Directory /srv/www/domain.com/htdocs/public/bitrix/cache>
        AllowOverride none
        Require all denied
    </Directory>

    <Directory /srv/www/domain.com/htdocs/public/bitrix/managed_cache>
        AllowOverride none
        Require all denied
    </Directory>

    <Directory /srv/www/domain.com/htdocs/public/bitrix/local_cache>
        AllowOverride none
        Require all denied
    </Directory>

    <Directory /srv/www/domain.com/htdocs/public/bitrix/stack_cache>
        AllowOverride none
        Require all denied
    </Directory>

    <Directory /srv/www/domain.com/htdocs/public/upload>
        AllowOverride none
        AddType text/plain php,php3,php4,php5,php6,phtml,pl,asp,aspx,cgi,dll,exe,ico,shtm,shtml,fcg,fcgi,fpl,asmx,pht
        php_value engine off
    </Directory>

    <Directory /srv/www/domain.com/htdocs/public/upload/support/not_image>
        AllowOverride none
        Require all denied
    </Directory>

    <Directory /srv/www/domain.com/htdocs/public/bitrix/images>
        AllowOverride none
        AddType text/plain php,php3,php4,php5,php6,phtml,pl,asp,aspx,cgi,dll,exe,ico,shtm,shtml,fcg,fcgi,fpl,asmx,pht
        php_value engine off
    </Directory>

    <Directory /srv/www/domain.com/htdocs/public/bitrix/tmp>
        AllowOverride none
        AddType text/plain php,php3,php4,php5,php6,phtml,pl,asp,aspx,cgi,dll,exe,ico,shtm,shtml,fcg,fcgi,fpl,asmx,pht
        php_value engine off
    </Directory>

    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        #Nginx should have "proxy_set_header HTTPS YES;" in location
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteCond %{HTTP:HTTPS} =YES
        RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTPS:on,L]
    </IfModule>

</VirtualHost>
```

I have tryed setup nginx like in laravel 8 documentation - no results
tryed change root folder to htdocs/public/public - The asset are includes well, but routes still 404 error
tryed config apache.conf in different ways - so still no results

**UPDATE**
i have added public/public in directory root conf both nginx & apache, and the assets include correctly, but the routes still give me 404 nginx error

Comment: Do you have nginx, or do you have apache? You can't usually run both. If you're running nginx, then the htaccess doesn't come into play, and if you're running apache, then ignore the nginx configuration and use the [default htaccess](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/laravel/laravel/10.x/public/.htaccess). But your document root should point to `/srv/www/domain.com/htdocs/public/public`, so that Laravel can serve the files correctly.

Comment: @aynber thank u for you advice, but i think i use both of them, because, when i change nginx conf or apache conf, the changes applyes (like set redirect to google in apache or disble ssl on nginx)

Comment: just missing pretty urls / url rewriting most likely

Comment: @aynber i have 404 nginx error page, when trying to accept the some route

Comment: @lagbox could u give me a hint, where i can check / fix it?

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/deployment#nginx

Comment: @lagbox saly but problem not solved, i stil get nginx 404 on all routes except /